# Google Play Music Chrome extension not working

Tags: google-chrome, music, chrome-extension

I'm trying to setup Chrome so I can upload some music to my Google Play Music account (which is how I upload from my Windows and Mac machines), however I cannot get the official Chrome Extension to work on Ubuntu...

I'm running 16.04 LTS on a new Dell XPS 13.

The first time I try to upload music via the Play Music web interface in Chrome I get prompted to install the extension, so I follow the prompts and install it.

Then when I try the upload again I get a bit further, but after selecting the files to upload I get a "Couldn't identify computer" error and no upload happens.

I've also noticed that if I try clicking on the Play Music icon from Chrome's apps page, or the icon it's installed into Ubuntu, nothing happens at all.

Please can anyone help?

Incidentally, the standalone Google Music Manager application works and uploads successfully, so the problem is definitely with the Chrome Extension.

I tried uploading using the Chrome Extension with the Music Manager still running in the background, but it made no difference.

My experience with the Music Manager on Windows is extremely flakey, so I would still prefer to get the Chrome Extension working instead...

Update 1:

This evening I tried installing a bleeding-edge daily Chromium build, manually setup the required API keys to allow me to sign-in (a laborious task for sure), and yet still encountered the exact same problems. So this rules out an out-of-date build being the cause.

Comment: I have the same problem. but even music manager on ubuntu does not work for me. Is music upload via music manager on linux or windows working for u?